# Haskell Shortest Path in Widget

Tags: haskell, tree, yesod, shortest-path

I'm building a web site in Haskell with Yesod. I have a widget that create different pages by changing the path :

```
module Handler.Page where

import Import

getPageR :: Int -> Handler Html
getPageR pageNumber = defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Castle Death page"
        $(widgetFile "page")

postPageR :: Int -> Handler Html
postPageR = error "Not yet implemented: postPageR"

getPage :: Int -> Widget
getPage 1 = [whamlet|
             <section class="txt">
                <h3><span class="headerContent">Page - 1
                <p>The hours leading up...
|]

getPage 135 = [whamlet|
                <section class="txt">
                    <h3><span class="headerContent">Page - 135</span></h3>
                    <p>A streak of green, ...
            |]

getPage 203 = [whamlet|
                <section class="txt">
                    <h3><span class="headerContent">Page - 203</span></h3>
                    <p> With your tremb...
            |]

getPage _ = error "This page is not implemented yet. Sorry!"
```

This works just fine. My pages load in the template. But I want to do a shortest path algorithm to see how much node I need to pass to get to the end.

I could do a data.tree to put my pages like :

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch [Tree a]
```

and then search the tree for the shortest path, but I would prefer a way to do it without a tree.

Thanks a lot!

-Edit-

I want to show how far the user is from the end. Ex : If there are 10 pages (1-100-105-110-205-304-355-400-458-500) and the final page is 304. Page 1 lead to 100 and 400 (the user choose witch). Then Page 100 lead to Page 105 and Page 110 and Page 500, ....

So if the user is at page 205 I want to be able to tell he he is at 75% of the path.

Comment: can you describe your question more clearly?

Comment: @jberryman I've editted my question to make it more clear.